# Password Reset Link doesn't work using Devise in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have overridden the Devise' password controller in my rails application. But it's not working properly. On click of 'reset password link', sometimes call to password#create goes into the gem or sometimes it goes into the overridden controller. My controller looks like:

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

  layout 'lunchbox/lunchbox', only: [:lunchbox_forgot, :lunchbox_recover]

  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)

    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    else
      flash[:error] = "Email not found"
      redirect_path = params[:user][:lunchbox] ? lunchbox_forgot_password_path : new_user_password_path
      redirect_to redirect_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you add this to your routes?   `devise_for :users, :controllers => {:passwords => "users/passwords"}`

Comment: Yes, i've added like:devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations", :passwords => "users/passwords", :sessions => "users/sessions"}